# how to append and replace word to another word in textarea from , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Change one word to another When active on a word, the word exists in an array
The words in the textare If they are not in the array at the same time
Context menu not active on all word, included a link to change one word to another
But the problem is that it doesn't work in the textarea you can help me fixed worked on textarea
[codepen contextmenu](https://codepen.io/rebaz-xoshnaw-the-builder/pen/XWOPvRe)

I've been looking for that for a long time how can I For a word that has textarea the custom context menu opened the word should be specific have in the array to recognize him Can anyone help me. That's just an example of a context menu, not in a textarea if textarea value does not have specificwords word It shouldn't be open The code I put as a suggestion for my request has nothing to do with the source

var specificwords = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'some', 'howdy'];

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
let contextMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-context-menu")[0];
specificwords = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'some', 'howdy'];
contextMenu.setAttribute("open", true);

textarea.oncontextmenu = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let string = event.target.value;
    let words = string.split(' ');
    let result = words.filter(word => specificwords.includes(word))

    if (result.length > 0) {
        let x = event.pageX, y = event.pageY;
        contextMenu.style.left = x + "px";
        contextMenu.style.top = y + "px";
        contextMenu.style.display = "block";

        contextMenu.classList.add("on");
    }
}

document.onclick = (event) => {
    if (contextMenu.classList.contains("on")) {
        contextMenu.classList.remove("on");
        contextMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.custom-context-menu {
    z-index: 1100;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}

.custom-context-menu li {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-context-menu li:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>hello This is some text. Click on any word and then do right click</textarea>
    <ul class="custom-context-menu">
        <li>rule</li>
        <li>slde</li>
        <li>rebaz</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use textarea.selectionStart / End like example...

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
let contextMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-context-menu")[0];
specificwords = ['hi', 'hello', 'yo', 'hey', 'some', 'howdy'];
contextMenu.setAttribute("open", true);

textarea.oncontextmenu = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let string = event.target.value;
  let words = string.split(' ');
  let result = words.filter(word => specificwords.includes(word))

  if (result.length > 0) {
    let x = event.pageX,
      y = event.pageY;
    contextMenu.style.left = x + "px";
    contextMenu.style.top = y + "px";
    contextMenu.style.display = "block";

    contextMenu.classList.add("on");
  }
}

document.onclick = (event) => {
  if (contextMenu.classList.contains("on")) {
    contextMenu.classList.remove("on");
    contextMenu.style.display = "none";

    let textContent = textarea.value;
    let start = Math.max(0, textContent.lastIndexOf(' ', textarea.selectionStart) + 1);
    let end = textContent.substr(textarea.selectionEnd);
    end = end.indexOf(' ');
    end = (end < 0 ? textContent.length : end) + textarea.selectionEnd;
    textarea.value = textContent.substr(0, start) +
      event.srcElement.innerText +
      textContent.substr(end);
  }
}
```

```css
.custom-context-menu {
  z-index: 1100;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.custom-context-menu li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-context-menu li:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea rows=4 cols=50>hello This is some text. Click on any word and then do right click</textarea>
  <ul class="custom-context-menu">
    <li>rule</li>
    <li>slde</li>
    <li>rebaz</li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Here all the words in the textarea are context menu opned
How to introduce some words in the array
  Only the words in the array should appear in the textarea                                     When the context menu becomes no options selected, a word is deleted
That's how it's going to be fixed

Comment: You can use similar logic in oncontextmenu - in my addition you already have start/end of the word, single substring can give you the word... textarea selection properties are available from this first click event.